# How to perform review on master

Tags: git

We (my team) developed code and did not commit the code to Git respository because it was not ready. Now, Git  is ready for our usage, however, our code development is done and then we created a project with a 'master' branch on Git.

So our developed (non-reviewed) code is on 'master'.

The problem is we want to do code review using Git's code review process.
However, how can we create a pull-request on master to merge with master?

What is the best approach?

Can I do the following ?

1. Create a branch out of master
2. Create pull request to merge this branch into master and add reviewres
3. Implement code review comments
4. Then override every master file where code review development is done

Comment: You should be branching and making pull requests onto master from those branches.

Comment: @Seiyria - what you said is correct but in ideal scenarios. We do not have an ideal scenario

Comment: Then you need to fix it, because you cannot do what you're trying to do, the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: @Seiyria Yes but how to fix it is the main question?

Comment: You can't make a pull request on a branch onto itself. That's what I've been trying to tell you.

Comment: @Seiyria I understand I can't merge master intto master. So what can i do to resolve this issue? 1. delete my code on master branch and create a new temp branch and create pull request , add reviewers and merge with master? OR 2. create a branch out of master, create pull request to merge this branch into master and add reviewres and then override every master file where code review development is done? OR any other appraoch ?

Comment: The first approach is what I was recommending in my first comment, so do that.

Comment: @Seiyria will that work when there is absolutely no code present on master branch but a new project is present in another branch and a pull request will create a new project on master as well?

Answer (score 0):

Steps I would take to resolve this:

1. Create a completely new repository
2. Set remote branch of current development environment to new repository
3. `git checkout -b new-dev-branch`
4. Commit work to new-dev-branch (on the new repository)
5. Create a Pull Request of new-dev-branch to master on new repository
6. Review Pull Request.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the repository.  Create a new blank repository. Branch that, and add your code to the branch.  Then continue the code review process.